# Upon deletion I want to set another value that is in the table (random) as the foreign Key, if i delete that foreign key, how can i do this?

Tags: mysql, database-design, ddl

For example, I have a database that has coaches and gymnastics, if a coach leaves the squad then every gymnast they are assigned too need to be randomly set a new coach.

This needs to be done in SQL DDL, so when the database is set up. I can't see this being done by CASCADE or SET NULL, so how? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That can't be done by DDL but you can create the trigger `BEFORE DELETE` for the table `Coaches` that will update all the related rows from another tables to preserve the referential consistency.

Comment: Thank You, when you I do this, in the implementation? (after the create table)..

Comment: Trigger can't be created for non-existent table so you have to create the table first and then you can create the corresponding trigger.

Comment: Ok say that this table is my gymnast table: 

CREATE TABLE Gymnast(
    Name VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    Type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
    IdCoach INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id),
    FOREIGN KEY (IdCoach) REFERENCES Coach(IdCoach)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE 
);

After creating the table, what appropriate trigger would allow the CoachID to be a random existing CoachID in the COACH table. 

Thank you for all your help :)

Answer (score 0):

That is a business logic task.  Do it in your application code, do not expect some magical SQL feature to do it for you.

You *could* build a `STORED PROCEDURE DeleteACoach` and have both steps (delete the coach and reassign his/her former team members).  But think of that as the encapsulation of business logic in SQL, *not* as an automatic Trigger or Foreign Key (or whatever).